# using openxml can't be opened in microsoft office 2016 but opened in wps office

Tags: openxml

I'd try to making file xlsx file in C# using openXML with following code:

```
            if (!File.Exists(@SpreadSheetFile))
        {
            try
            {

                // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
                // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
                SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(SpreadSheetFile, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

                // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
                WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

                // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
                Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

                // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
                Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = sheetName };
                sheets.Append(sheet);

                workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

                // Close the document.
                spreadsheetDocument.Close();
                isNewFileAndSheetCreated = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                throw new System.InvalidOperationException(SpreadSheetFile + " tidak dapat dibuat" + Environment.NewLine + ee.Message);
            }
```

can't be opened in microsoft office 2016 but opened in wps office.
Please help is there anything wrong with code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I updated openXML to version 2.7 after I found in github. It says:

> News: The Office2016 branch on this repo contains a preview of the Open-Xml-Sdk v2.7, which supports the Office 2016 extensions in the file format.

I was using 2.5 downloaded from microsoft website which (I think) was not support office 2016. It is solved.